# Why doesn't the toggle toggle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slidetoggle

Newb here attempting to learn how to do work with jQuery by way of investigating 'the toggle'

I have a very simple html page and I thought that the second link would load as collapsed/hidden and  that when clicked it would reveal it's contents, but it does not. Instead everything displays to the screen with all the inner html exposed (Hope i'm using terms correctly). I believe that what is happening is that the jQuery is not loading, but thats only the best guess of a hobbyist, hopefully someone out there can help me to get this to work.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $.fn.slideFadeToggle = function(speed, easing, callback) {
            return this.animate({
                opacity: 'toggle',
                height: 'toggle'
            }, speed, easing, callback);
        };

        // Collapse everything but the first menu:
        $("#accordionMenu  li  a").not(":first").find("+ ul").slideUp(1);

        // Expand or collapse:
        $("#accordionMenu  li  a").click(function() {
            $(this).find("+ ul").slideFadeToggle("500");
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="firstDiv">
        <div id="secondDiv">
            <ul id="accordionMenu">
                <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">menu item</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">suboption 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">submenu expandable</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">suboption 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">suboption 2</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: It appears to be working fine in this jsFiddle <http://jsfiddle.net/2n88t/> , if you open developer tools and the network tab is it fetching jquery-1.8.3.min.js alright?

Comment: When I open the developer tools (Safari) and look I don't see any errors or warnings. And it looks like jQuery 1.8.3 is loading as i can see that showing in the resource pane. I've also look at it with chrome, again it appears that jQuery is loading.

Comment: Here is a url: http://school.max-o-matic.com/study/test.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code need to be in a [dom ready handler](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/). In your case you are trying to add the event handler to the target elements before those elements are loaded in the dom, so those handlers will not get registered.

```
//dom ready handler
jQuery(function ($) {
    $.fn.slideFadeToggle = function (speed, easing, callback) {
        return this.animate({
            opacity: 'toggle',
            height: 'toggle'
        }, speed, easing, callback);
    };

    // Collapse everything but the first menu:
    $("#accordionMenu  li  a").not(":first").find("+ ul").slideUp(1);

    // Expand or collapse:
    $("#accordionMenu  li  a").click(function () {
        //use .next() here
        $(this).next("ul").slideFadeToggle("500");
    });
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/72AzK/)

Comment: A 'Dom Handler', yes that seems to have been the problem. Thank you for the link to Dom Handlers, I will be reading through this tonight, and tomorrow morning - so much to learn - as always web remains exciting - thank you.